# Apache memory error

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

As I was trying to restart apache2, I encountered the following error:

> Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864
>   bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)

I only found out that this error often occures on virtual servers, but I couldn't find a solution oter than switching to php-fpm and nginx to reduce memory use.

Server: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 2GB RAM, VPS

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue, because RAM doesn't seem to be the problem (1.9GB free).

Sodaa

Comment: Only happen on graceful restarts?  Or when?  And what are  `shmmax`/`shmall` set to?

Comment: No not only on graceful starts. max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Fatal Error Unable to allocate **shared memory segment**".

Use `ipcs -lm` to determine current shared memory limits.  And use `ipcs -ma` to determine how much shared memory is currently in use.

**UPDATE** you have added the comment to show "max seg size (kbytes) = 32768".  So max segment size is 32MB.  Original error is "Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes".  So unable to allocate segment of 64MB.

Increase your maximum shared memory segment size from 32MB to 128MB.

```
echo "134217728" >/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
echo "134217728" >/proc/sys/kernel/shmall
```

And then retry.  If apache2 then works ok, make the change survive reboots, by placing an entry in /etc/sysctl.conf as below:

```
kernel.shmmax=134217728
kernel.shmall=134217728
```

Comment: the limits are:
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 32768
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1

ipcs -ma returns no numbers ...

Comment: ri Jun 15 14:28:00 2018 (1202): Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes: shmget: Cannot allocate memory (12), /etc/apache2# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
134217728
/etc/apache2# cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
134217728 does not solve the problem

Comment: Works! But i had to add the memory limits in /etc/sysctl.conf like posted here https://mage2.pro/t/topic/2271  Also a full reboot (not only apache restart!) was needed